# F# abstract member has to be public?

Tags: f#

It seems that if I declare an abstract member in a base class (so that derived class can override it), this member must be public.

However, there're cases that I don't want to expose such member as a public method. It's just for internal implementation where virtual dispatch is needed.

Since F# has no "protected", is it possible to at least make it "internal"?

Thanks!

---

Some context:

I'm doing some work in an existing non-small F# code base. It has already using inheritance intensively (so refactor out inheritance is not viable at the moment though it might be the right thing).

In a specific case, there are following types

```
type Base<'U> () =
   // blah blah

type Derived1<'K, 'V when 'K equality> () =
   inherit Base<'K * 'V>()
   // Blah blah

type Derived2<'U> () =
   inherit Base<'U>() 
   // Blah blah
```

Now for one thing I intended to do, if I do it with abstract thus can take advantage of virtual dispatching, I will add an abstract member in Base as

```
 abstract member Member: unit -> Base<'U>
```

Then in Derived1 add

```
 override x.Member () =
   y = // blah blah
   y :> Base<_>
```

And in Derived2 add

```
 override x.Member () =
   y = // blah blah
   y :> Base<_>
```

Then I can use "Member" in other places inside Base type.

The problem is that "Member" becomes "public", but it's only for some internal implementation need.  Since there's no "protected", I'd hope I can use "internal".  However, it's not allowed by compiler either (any idea about the reasoning here?).  How could I achieve similar thing without using "abstract" member? (and without changing the current inheritance chain, which already has tons of code ...)

Thanks very much for any suggestions!

Comment: That's correct - since F# does not have `protected`, you have to make all `abstract` members public. Can you write more about your scenario? Inheritance can usually be avoided in F#, which resolves this problem (and often makes code nicer).

Comment: I think most of OO features in F# implemented for interoperations with standard .NET libraries and existing C# (or VB) code. If you need to add some new F# code to existing C# codebase maybe it is better to "wrap" new F# functionality by C# interface of class.

Comment: first of I don't think that `internal` would be allowed in C# either - as your `Base<_>` is public a user should be able to make derived classes on his own - which he might not if abstract members would be abstract.

Comment: Try to take a step back and answer the wider question: why do you think you need to make a member `protected` or `internal` in the first place? FWIW, I've been doing OOP for more than a decade, and consider the use of these C# key words a strong design smell: it's basically telling me that that part of my design doesn't properly address **encapsulation**.

Comment: Here is the use case, wrapping an external C# class hierarchy with the similar F# friendly one and completely hiding the original details using `internal` members.